# Export font as physical file in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

I'm finding a way to export/extract font(UIFont, CGFont, CTFont, or NSFont) in the system into physical font file(OTF, TTF, WOFF, etc..).

I'm aware that there's way to convert 'file' or String into Data then write it into the storage by providing file path and file name.

My application includes some custom fonts where I can retrieve from the bundle level and register into the app. But there's a problem whereby the user is using the system font and I couldn't find a way to export UIFont -> Data -> Write to disk (font.otf).

The purpose of this is the sync font used on documents/notes across different app platform. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it. You don't have access to the device's built-in fonts as *files*.